"args"' does not exist in type 'StoryProps'
I am using storybook with svelkit, and i got this error with latest storybook update that args does not exist in type StoryProps, Here is my storybook code, error is in when i am making story with different variants.I am using latest version of storybook and sveltekit.
<script context="module" lang="ts">
    import { Story, Template } from '@storybook/addon-svelte-csf';
    import { Button } from '..';

    export const meta = {
        title: 'Button',
        component: Button
    };
</script>

<Template let:args>
    <Button {...args} />
</Template>

<Story
    name="Primary"
    args={{
        args: { variant: 'primary' },
        l10n: { label: 'Button' },
        handlers: { click: () => alert('clicked') }
    }}
/>

<Story
    name="Secondary"
    args={{
        args: { variant: 'secondary', primarySvg: true, secondarySvg: false },
        l10n: { label: 'sign in with google' },
        content: { primaryIconSrc: '/images/Button/Icon.svg' },
        handlers: { click: () => alert('clicked') }
    }}
/>

<Story
    name="SecondaryTwo"
    args={{
        args: {
            variant: 'secondary',
            primarySvg: false,
            secondarySvg: true
        },
        l10n: { label: 'Button' },
        content: { secondaryIconSrc: '/images/Button/Arrow.svg' },
        handlers: { click: () => alert('clicked') }
    }}
/>

<Story
    name="Tertiary"
    args={{
        args: { variant: 'tertiary' },
        l10n: { label: 'Button' },
        content: { secondaryIconSrc: '/images/Button/Arrow.svg' },
        handlers: { click: () => alert('clicked') }
    }}
/>

<Story
    name="Danger"
    args={{
        args: {
            variant: 'danger',
            backgroundColor: 'var(--danger)',
            borderColor: 'var(--transparent)'
        },
        l10n: { label: 'Button' },
        handlers: { click: () => alert('clicked') }
    }}
/>

<Story
    name="Disabled"
    args={{
        args: {
            variant: 'disabled'
        },
        l10n: { label: 'Button' },
        handlers: { click: () => null }
    }}
/>

I am expecting a new syntax of storybook with sveltekit.
